# Suma de matrices

Tags: matrices, dev-c++

Tengo que sumar la matriz original con la matriz (transpuesta) que está multiplicada por 3, pero no he podido dar con la suma, les agradecería mucho si me pudieran ayudar a saber qué tengo que hacer para sumar ambas matrices. A continuación adjunto mi código.
Nota: Las bibliotecas tipo wchar y locale los usé para poner acentos

`#include<time.h>`
`#include<conio.h>`
`#include<stdlib.h>`
`#include<stdio.h>`
`#include <wchar.h>`
`#include <locale.h>`
`using namespace std;`

`//El múltiplo debe ser 3.`

`int main()`
`{ int s=0,A[4][4],B[4][4],C[4][4],i,j,inf,sup,m;`
`srand(time(NULL));`
`setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

```
printf("Dame el límite inferior de la matriz y el límite superior de la matriz: \n");
scanf("%d %d",&inf,&sup);
printf("\nEl múltiplo de la matriz es 3, por lo que queda de la siguiete forma:\n");

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        do
        {
            A[i][j]=rand()%(sup-inf)+inf;
        }while(A[i][j]%3!=0);
        printf("%d\t",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n\n");
printf("La transpuesta es:\n");

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",A[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n¿Qué número quieres multiplicarle a la matriz transpuesta?: ");
scanf("%d",&m);

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        A[j][i]*=m;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",A[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hablas de matriz traspuesta y está la multiplicas por 3 mi pregunta es si estás operaciones no tienes que hacerlas ya que solo quieres sumar las matrices

Comment: Sí es necesario, mi profesora me lo ha pedido así.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la suma de matrices es tan simple como que sumes la posición homologa de cada dato en las matrices, es decir (a11,a12,a13) +(b11,b12,b13) = (a11 + b11,a12 + b12, a13 + b13) en otras palabras, debes meter las dos matrices en un ciclo for anidado, y usar la misma variable de posición para las dos, es decir el mismo iterador y haga la operacion que necesitas hacer, en tu caso sumar. Ejemplo

```
for(i....){

    for (j ...){
     matrix1[i][j] = suma1[i][j] +suma2[i][j];
    }

}
```

Creo es lo que quieres.

Comment: Tu código no está muy claro, trata de mejorarlo

Comment: Mmmm, vale, lo intentaré, gracias.